# Can't make width greater than 200px

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a textbox and textarea that I want to encrease the width on. I can't make the width larger than the default, but I can make it less. The default width is around 200px

Here is the code for the control:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        ...
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NoteTextViewModels.First().ContextIdentifier, new { @class = "timeAndNote" })
        </td>
...
```

And the css:

```
.timeAndNote{
       width: 500px;
   }
```

I am using JQuery dialog to show the data:

```
<div id="noteDialogDiv" style="display: none;"></div>
```

And JS function:

```
function showDetailedImage(divId, dialogTitle) {
var target = '#' + divId;
$(target).attr("title", dialogTitle);

var dialog = $(target).dialog({
        show: "clip",
        hide: "clip",
        height: $(window).height() / 3,
        width: $(window).width() / 3 ,
        title: dialogTitle,
        modal:true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
});
dialog.dialog('open');
```

}

Is there something I don't know of, that prevents a user from encreasing the width on some controls in some occassions?

I have added an image, where there are 2 arrows pointing at the controls I want to make wider:
[image]

Comment: did you check if there is no parent element setting "max-width" to 200 ? it might be inheriting max-width: 200 from somewhere.

Comment: Yeah, the parent width is at least 800px

Comment: can you set up the scenario in jsfiddle or alikes ?

Answer (score 9):

If I had to guess, I'd say that the max-width is actually 280px. I can guess that because the Site.css file generated by the default MVC project template has the following style definition:

```
/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Remove that, and you should be good. Whoever did the sample template for MVC 5 got lazy and took a shortcut to make the default forms look good, instead of actually using the Bootstrap grid as you're supposed to.

Comment: I edited my post by adding an image of the issue for a more visual example

Comment: Okay. And did you check Site.css to see if this is there?

Comment: Yes it is there. Won't I encounter problems if I remove the max-width here?

Comment: Maybe at first, as you'll have to properly format any forms that were not setup correctly in the first place because of this. However, better now, than later.

Comment: 4 years later, still wasting developers' time with this.

Answer (score 1):

Like Chris Pratt mentions, the issue is that there is a max width on the controls. I tried adding:`max-width: 600px`, then it worked.

Thanks a lot for all your input guys. And thanks Chris

Comment: 1) I'd simply remove the max-width entirely. Bootstrap inputs are supposed to be 100% wide, so the grid can be used with them. By setting a max-width, you'll be breaking all sorts of functionality, like input addons. 2) This should not be posted as an answer. Either make a comment on my answer or update your question.

Comment: So will I encounter problems by solving it with setting a max-width on just these 2 controls that I am dealing with?